# JNI - passing content of html file from C side to Java side

Tags: android, java-native-interface

the HTML file has an encoding like windows-1254 and I have UTF-8, is it possible that it's leading a run-time error?
Can I change the character encoding on the C++ side?
Can I convert char* to a byte array?
what are the possible solutions for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look here

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jni/html/other.html 
(section "8.2 Writing Internationalized Code")

The function you might be interested in converting a native encoded string to a jstring (and eventually passing it to java-side, is JNU_NewStringNative

```
jstring JNU_NewStringNative(JNIEnv *env, const char *str)
 {
     jstring result;
     jbyteArray bytes = 0;
     int len;
     if ((*env)->EnsureLocalCapacity(env, 2) < 0) {
         return NULL; /* out of memory error */
     }
     len = strlen(str);
     bytes = (*env)->NewByteArray(env, len);
     if (bytes != NULL) {
         (*env)->SetByteArrayRegion(env, bytes, 0, len,
                                    (jbyte *)str);
         result = (*env)->NewObject(env, Class_java_lang_String,
                                    MID_String_init, bytes);
         (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, bytes);
         return result;
     } /* else fall through */
     return NULL;
 }
```

cheers,